# Unable to perform xAxis[0].setCategories & series[0].setData

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hii All,
I am passing values dynamically for a chart, using set data and set categories method. I have attached the fiddle link, which loads a sample chart and a button, when clicked which sets the data and categories for the chart. The setData(yaxis) and setCategory(xaxis) is not workin for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/byfour/XUgAQ/13/

Please help!

Many thanks,
byfour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quoting the data as though it were a string;

```
var ydata = '[129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]';
```

whereas it should be an array:

```
var ydata = [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4];
```

If they are "incoming" as strings for some reason? you can convert them;

```
var ydata = '[129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4]';
ydata = ydata.substr(1, ydata.length - 2).split(",");
chart.series[0].setData(ydata );
```